# Ubuntu still identify .exe application, however I have remove WineHQ

Tags: wine, uninstall, executable, installed-programs

I have remove `WineHQ` in via terminal completely and other `WineHQ` configuration. But, Ubuntu still identify `.exe` application, not likely never install `WineHQ` before.

How to remove all `WineHQ` programs, including icons, configuration, and the other objects that it cannot identify `.exe` app again? Because I'm afraid that it can spread the malware like Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can try wine uninstaller GUI

uninstaller is a GUI uninstaller for all setup programs that put an uninstall entry in the registry, e.g. InstallShield or the WISE installer. It's similar in function to "Add/Remove Programs" in Windows, except much simpler.

Usage:

wine uninstaller

Reference: http://wiki.winehq.org/uninstaller

Answer (score 0):

No you have not completely removed wine although you un-installed it.

Go through following steps to completely remove it:

- Open terminal and execute these command to remove **Wine** with configuration file.

  ```
  sudo apt-get autoremove wine*
  sudo apt-get --purge remove wine*
  sudo apt-get autoremove
  sudo apt-get autoclean
  ```
- Now finally execute following command to remove icons, and other files:

  ```
  sudo find / | grep -v '/var/cache/apt/archives' | grep wine | sudo xargs rm -r -f
  ```
- That's it.. Once reboot your system if it still detect.

  ```
  sudo reboot
  ```

Comment: I have uninstall via "Synaptic Package Manager", including following via your terminal but it still same.

Comment: Repeat it again, this time very precisely! And don't forget to execute `2nd` point.. Restart your system.. :)

Comment: You can simply pass `--purge` as an option to `apt-get autoremove` rather than running both autoremove, and then remove.

Comment: I was lack of confidence. I have try it and I think it also delete all Ubuntu configuration program, not only Wine, when I see via Terminal that I try your techniques.

Comment: No it will never delete other Ubuntu files.. Until you do some mistake.. ;) Don't hesitate to run this.. Be confident this time. :P